# Programmatically uncheck md-checkbox in angluarjs

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

[here is my design screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn1Tp.png) i want Programmatically uncheck md-checkbox in AngularJS based on the id. whenever user click close mark(x) than equivalent checkbox need to uncheck

Answer (score 1):

If you use ng-model you can just set the property to false.

Comment: i use ng-repeat for populate checkbox dynamically. i use checkbox's for filter. once user select checkbox i display that value separately with close mark. when user click that close mar i need to unchecked the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ng-checked

Comment: i use ng-repeat for populate checkbox dynamically. i use checkbox's for filter. once user select checkbox i display that value separately with close mark. when user click that close mar i need to unchecked  the checkbox.